# Output I2S master clock RK3399

Tags: i2s

Don't know how to output I2S master clock to a pin header.

I'm using a board with RPI-like 40-pin header and RK3399 chip. I'm able to get I2S in/out signal (BCLK, LRCLK, DATA) with alsa, but I need also a master clock signal (MCLK) for working with ADC. What should I do? Are there any examples how to output additional MCLK signal to a pin header?